# trying to print search "label" and "description" without printing anything else within the page

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

Something is wrong with my code but I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.
What I am trying to do accomplish is that when the "Print" button is clicked, dynamically populate the "print" div with content drawn from the "screen" div, before calling window.print()
I had it explained to me like this

> have two main child divs within your body tags.   styled to be displayed under @media screen and hidden under @media print.   styled to be displayed under @media print and hidden under @media screen

Here's a fiddle for my attempt. Any help appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/59rphg1h/1/

```
        <ul>
      <li><b>No Print</b>..Don't print anything before the following search box</li>
      <li><b>No Print</b>..No graphics, Ads or anything else before the search box and its results</li>
    </ul>
      <div id="print">
      <div id="screen">

        <form class="printForm">
          <div id="printReady">
            <div class="autocompleter">
              <label> When you see a </label>
              <input type=search placeholder="&#x1f50d; Search Box Type here, Then Click Print!" name="tryit" data-using="tryit">
                <p class="content">&nbsp;</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
                            <input type="button" onClick="window.print();" value="Print this Recipe">
        <script>
    autocompleter.tryit = [
        {
            value: "Print this display too!",
            label: "Type then Select...,",
            desc: "<ol> <h3>When clicked print, how can I:</h3> <li> keep List for print, and eliminate everything else on the page?</li> <li> still keep the selected text (results of the search) which says --Print this display too!--</li></ol>",
        }
    ];
        </script>
        <ul>
          <li><b>No Print</b>..Don't print anything After the search box and its results</li>
          <li><b>No Print</b>..No graphics, Ads or anything else After the search box and its results</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude/include specific HTML elements from a page when printing by a **print media query**.

Example:

```
@media print { 
   /* All your print styles go here */
   #header, #footer, #nav {
     display: none !important;
   } 

   ol {
     display: block !important;
   }
}
```

For more info about print media query you can read this [article](http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/).

So if you add the dynamic content (the `ol` tag) you need initially to the page with `display: none` it will not be displayed but will be printed because the print media query will override it.

Comment: Did you try it in the fiddle. I can't get that to work. will look a little deeper but try using it with the jsfiddle

Comment: Make two new classes `print-only` and `screen-only`.
Add all your content to the page, assign the `print-only` class for elements that you want to show only in print, and the `screen-only` class for elements that are to be shown only in normal view and add the following css to your page:
`@media screen { 
   
   .print-only {
     display: none !important;
   } 

   .screen-only {
     display: block !important;
   }
}

@media print { 
   
   .print-only {
     display: block !important;
   } 

   .screen-only {
     display: none !important;
   }
}`

Comment: I could not get the jsfiddle to respond within the searchbox (not sure what is going on there). However, I did type a few words into it and the print was successful in removing the lists. I wonder now if that will remove the rest of the web page as well.  In my code I placed <ul><li></li></ul> as an example for something to remove during my tests. <ul class="screen-only"> to remove the lists works. A lot of my problem is the rest of the web page as well.

Comment: Regarding your concern just add the `screen-only` class to any HTML element you don't want to be printed, and the `print-only` class to any HTML element you don't want to show on the screen.

Comment: There are a lot of elements to eliminate, ie hearder, footer, navs, etc., could you offer an example to eliminate them.

Comment: You can put the `screen-only` on the `<body>` element, that will make everything not printable, then specify the `print-only` class on the elements you need to print.
And if you can update the fiddle with the whole HTML I can help you more of course :)

Comment: That code works on my editor and prints as expected. However, on the fiddle, print won't work. The <ol class=print-only"></ol> option created problems, I eliminated it, fixed the @media css and it seems fine. will work with the <ol></ol> in css and see if I can fix that too. last issue was the print button showing at print time. because of this, I hid it     <button class="screen-only">  <input type="button" onClick="window.print();" value="Print">  </button> but fiddle won't print now but it does print without the button showing on my end, from my editor.

Comment: A general note on using jsfiddle: don't add tags in the CSS and Javascript boxes, use plain text only.

Comment: Tha'er that did it. I am so happy with the help you offered and results. I commend your efforts here. The example fiddle was a small snippet for my web pages and now need to transfer this concept to my site. Hope this helps others some day. Much appreciated!